# What is relevant ROS packages for walking quadruped?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to design walking quadruped robot with sprawling configuraion using Dynamixel servo. The navigation use SLAM with XV-LiDAR 11 input. I look on the internet and found [towr](http://wiki.ros.org/towr) and [Moveit!](https://moveit.ros.org/) packages seems can handle the kinematic but I am afraid both will overkill because my robot is should be optimized to walk on even surface in a maze. Maybe package with seamless integration with navigation stack, kinematic, and gait will be much better.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291739/what-is-relevant-ros-packages-for-walking-quadruped?/) by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2018-05-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hari Prasanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/35475/hari-prasanth/) on 2018-05-29**:
hi there! I am also looking for the same. did you get any solution??

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2018-05-30**:
@Hatty_pcott, Hi! I still working on the navigation until next three months. I think we should work together. Do you mind to share your robot project specs? feel free to contact me at `fathoni.id@gmail.com`

**Comment by [crank](https://answers.ros.org/users/38081/crank/) on 2018-10-18**:
So have you try quadruped in moveit or towr? I still have some problems in moveit_setup_assosant and i'm still find some way to display and control quadruped in moveit.thank you for your adviese!

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2018-10-23**:
@crank yes, but I still focus on robot navigation. I will do more research about this package and tell you the result.

**Comment by [facureyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/51632/facureyes/) on 2020-02-28**:
@achmad_fathoni @crank Hey guys, Im working on a quadruped robot too and I have the same question as you, is it better to work with move it or with towr? In any case, do you find a good tutorial that might help me? thanks in advance!

**Comment by [akashnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/52175/akashnambiar/) on 2020-03-03**:
did any of you guys find anything? I am currently working on the same.

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2020-03-04**:
Your post is not an answer, use comment section instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For general leg locomotion gait please check [towr](http://wiki.ros.org/towr) package.

---

Originally posted by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) with karma: 96 on 2020-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0